# How to convert dd/mm/yyyy to mm/dd/yyyy in LimeSurvey

Tags: mysql, datetime, business-objects, limesurvey

I have an issue with LimeSurvey. Our URL has variables that were created via LimeSurvey. For example, https://poll.company.com/index.php/survey/index/sid/123456/newest/y?&ticket=IR123456&createddate=1/31/2018&resolveddate=2/1/2018&closeddate=2/3/2018

Now, & allows to pass multiple values... the variables ticket, createddate, resolveddate, and closeddate were created in LimeSurvey as a question code resembling the question. Keep in mind the questions are text fields. In our SCSM (helpdesk system for creating incidents) server there is a E-mail template that has the URL created. The values for the variables that I mentioned above are inserted or embedded inside of SCSM.. So ticket=SCSM variable where SCSM variable is the variable that is embedded in the SCSM template.

My issue is that the date format in the URL is mm/dd/yyyy and it works perfectly for users with that format in their OS. However, users with different date/time format such as dd/mm/yyyy or dd.mm.yyyy in mySQL formats it in its native format, but when we run the reports in Business Objects it is blank or null.

Theory is when users submit the survey it is posted to the mySQL database depending on the users locale in other words their date/time format according to where their time zone is.

Any ideas?? LimeSurvey is the tool. We use Information Design Tool (Universe) to tie the LimeSurvey database and SCSM database to report in Business Objects where the data will be depicted.

Thank you!!

Comment: MySQL or SQL Server? In any case *don't* pass localized strings in the URL. Use the ISO8601 format so you *don't* have to guess

Comment: So, if I get it right. The resolve_date parameter prefills the LS resolve_date question. Resolve_date parameter gets a wrong date format and LS saves resolve_date as it is given.

Is that the case?

Answer (score 0):

Limesurvey version ? Because in last version of LimeSurvey, it need to use SQL date (ISO8601) only for prefilling date value. 
Because of your issue .

If you are in the last version , maybe a bug.